# Mapping an array of values to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

So I have an issue that requires me to map an array of names to an object with a property of name.

The following code is in question:

```
this.planNames.map((name,index) => {
     this.tempdata[index].name = name;
        }),
```

Here is an example of the array.

```
tempdata: any = [
    {
      name: 'Mix and match',
      title: 'Single-line plans for voice messaging and data.',
      desc:
        'A great plan option for businesses that want each line on its own plan. These plans have no maximum line caps.',
    },
    {
      name: 'Flexible',
      title: 'Multi-line plans for when one size does not fit all.',
      desc:
        'A great plan option for up to 10 phones with different unlimited data needs',
    }
```

Any idea using arrow functions would be great as I am learning more about these myself.

Comment: What's `planNames`, and what's your desired output? Is the `tempdata` in your question the desired output or the input?

Comment: does you example code work? It looks like it should. However, you should use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: The out put is temp data. The issue is mapping from the names array to the temp data object array. Using the plan name array to update the value of tempdata.name property.

Comment: You should really show the input too. Right now the question is similar to asking "*How do I add numbers? Example output: 42*".

Answer (score 0):

There should be some changes in your map function.

```
this.planNames.map((item,index) => {
   this.tempdata[index].name = item.name;
});
console.log(this.tempData)
```

Answer (score -1):

The `map` function is only to replace data by others in array.
If you want to update other array data, you should use a `for` loop:

```js
const tempdata = [
    {
      name: 'Mix and match',
      title: 'Single-line plans for voice messaging and data.',
      desc:
        'A great plan option for businesses that want each line on its own plan. These plans have no maximum line caps.',
    },
    {
      name: 'Flexible',
      title: 'Multi-line plans for when one size does not fit all.',
      desc:
        'A great plan option for up to 10 phones with different unlimited data needs',
    }
];

const planNames = ['a', 'b'];

for(let i = 0; i < planNames.length; i++) {
  tempdata[i].name = planNames[i];
}

console.log(tempdata);
```

Answer (score -1):

[`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array containing the result of each of the original array elements passed through the callback function. So, you don't need to create a temporary array beforehand - the result of the map function will contain what you need.

```js
const newTempData = this.planNames.map((name, index) => {
   return { ...tempdata[i], name }
});
```

You don't generally mutate data in a `.map` function. If you're interested in mutating the original data structure, `tempdata`, you should just use a standard [`[].forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
tempdata.forEach((data, index) => {
    data.name = this.planNames[index];
});
```

Comment: much appreciated for the responses.

Comment: Thank you for all the great responses. I am just getting familiar with many of these array functions in JavaScript.